# Splitting an element on a tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

If I have an element that looks like so

```
<li> this is before <span class="between"> this is between </span> this is after </li>
```

How can I obtain the array `{"this is before", "this is after"}` using JSoup?

Note: the text could contain several `span`s, but only one of class `between`. So for example,

```
<li> 
this 
<span class="other"> is </span> 
before 
<span class="between"> this is between </span> 
this is 
<span class="other"> after </span> 
</li>
```

should also produce  `{"this is before", "this is after"}` .

Comment: When you say `this is before` , is it first one or second one

Comment: `this is before` is the piece of text before the `span`

Comment: if there are more `span`s , you want the text between all spans before span with between class and the text after the between class span?

Comment: yes exactly, i will update with an example with multiple `span`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `li`'s childnodes:

```
final String html = "<li> \n"
        + "this \n"
        + "<span class=\"other\"> is </span> \n"
        + "before \n"
        + "<span class=\"between\"> this is between </span> \n"
        + "this is \n"
        + "<span class=\"other\"> after </span> \n"
        + "</li>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element li = doc.select("li").first();
List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for( Node node : li.childNodes() ) // Iterate over childnodes
{
    if( node instanceof TextNode ) // Plain text
    {
        sb.append(node.toString());
    }
    else if( node instanceof Element ) // Element
    {
        final Element element = (Element) node;

        if( element.tagName().equals("span") // Span with 'between' class
                && element.attr("class").equals("between") == true )
        {
            text.add(sb.toString().trim());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
        else // Every other element
        {
            sb.append(element.ownText());
        }
    }
}

text.add(sb.toString().trim());

System.out.println(text);
```

**Output:**

```
[this is before, this is after]
```

Comment: dang nice, I was trying to do it with regex only :P

Comment: Hehe, you can do (almost) everything with jsoup too ;-D